# Piping text into netcat using WScript.Exec

Tags: vbscript, netcat

I'm playing a CTF and looking to pipe some content into netcat in order to illicit a response from an application listening on a port.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.Run "C:\\users\\me\\Desktop\\my_app.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Exec "echo hello > C:\\users\\me\\Desktop\\netcat\\nc.exe 127.0.0.1 4444"
```

What I get is an error

```
WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Which I presume is about the echo command as removing it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `my_app.exe`?

Comment: just an app which creates a socket on 4444

Comment: Try [`StdIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yzzwsz3t(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: What netcat and Win versions do you have?

Comment: think i found what im looking for, by using a .bat file as opposed to vbs. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@m0atz as @omegastripes mentioned, you need to use StdIn. The following demonstrates how:

```
Dim wshShell, oExec, buffer

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("C:\\users\\me\\Desktop\\netcat\\nc.exe 127.0.0.1 4444")

oExec.StdIn.Write "hello" & vbCrLf

buffer = ""
While Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    buffer = buffer & oExec.StdOut.Read(1)
Wend
WScript.Echo buffer
```